# Regular expression libraries for Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: objective-c, regex, pcre

Is there a library compatible with PCRE that can be used on Mac OS X 10.6, and which is Unicode compatible?

I was thinking to use the predicates, but it is a little excessive when the application is not already using Spotlight predicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [RegexKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I was hoping for something more than a 0.6 beta. If this is the only alternative to use predicates, then I will use RegexKit.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/).  While it's not quiet as full featured as the full RegexKit it's more actively developed, and is usable on both the iphone and desktop apps.

It's also a very very small addition to your app not having much impact on the end executable size.

Comment: RegexKitLite requires to link with a library that ships with Mac OS X, but the operation is not officially supported. The only official way to link with the ICU library is to use the Spotlight predicates, which was what I was trying to avoid.
It seems the only solution is to use RegexKit, also because I need to create a Automator action.

Comment: While this is true, I also tried to use RegexKit first.  Due to the additional file size that it caused and some issues I had developing against it I choose the unsupported but pragmatic method.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [OgreKit](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?OgreKit), used by TextMate, and apparently SubEthaEdit and some other heavy-hitters

Answer (score 1):

In addition to RegexKit and OgreKit, there are a couple other options here: http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/regex

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to the frameworks already reported, there is also `OFRegularExpression`, which is part of [OmniFoundation](http://www.omnigroup.com/developer/). As it is part of a bigger framework, it could not be the right choice, or it should be considered if other parts of the framework are required.